# How many processes (including the parent) will be created assuming each fork successfully executes

Tags: operating-system, fork

I believe that this creates 5 processes; however, I need verification. These questions often stump me. Thanks for the help!

```
void forktest()
{
   printf("L0\n");
   if (fork() != 0) 
   { 
       printf("L1\n");
       if (fork() != 0)
       {
           printf("L2\n");
           fork();
       }
   }
   printf("Bye\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main
   |
   |
fork  --- (first child)
   |
   |
fork  --- (second child)
   |
   |
fork  --- (third child)
```

---

```
void forktest()
{
   printf("L0\n");
   if (fork() != 0) <----- first child, only parent goes inside the if
   { 
       printf("L1\n");
       if (fork() != 0) <------ second child, only parent goes inside the if
       {
           printf("L2\n"); 
           fork();       <------ third child
       }
   }
   printf("Bye\n");
}
```

That is, 3 processes created by main.